# Update Label text in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am new to Xamarin and am trying to create a simple app to upload my mobile images to cloud and download them from cloud. I was able to upload and download the files from cloud. Now I want to show some progress status, while uploading/downloading the files. I have the count of images i want to upload, so I was thinking to create a label on my xaml form and update its value after every picture upload. Example. if Total pictures are 5 and the loop used to upload the images have uploaded 2 pictures. I'll show "2 of 5 Images uploaded" as text in my label.

My code structure is like this :

```
1. Mainfile.xaml

<Label x:Name="UpdatedStatus" Text="No file to Update" />  // my label to show status
<Button Text="Upload Image" x:Name="btnUpload" Clicked="OnUploadClick" />

2. Mainfile.xaml.cs
//Implementation of OnUploadClick
private async void OnBackUpButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  UploadClass upload = new UploadClass();
  await upload.UploadImageFunction(); // reference of function to upload the image
}

3. UploadClass.cs
//actual implementation of function to upload image
public async Task UploadImageFunction()
{ 
  //logic to get the count of the images to upload
  foreach (image in TotalImages)
  {
    try
    {
       await UploadToCloud(images);
       /* How can I update up label from here for every upload. 
       I was able to update the label 2nd file but not from this. 
       I was trying something like
       UpdatedStatus.Text = "updated file 1"; 
       But this is not working.*/
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
      // logic in case of any error 
    }
 }
}
```

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: allowing UploadClass to directly update the UI of a completely separate page would be a violating of multiple OO principles.  A much cleaner approach would to have UploadClass raise an event every time it completes an upload, so that any page/class using it can update its UI (or not) as it chooses.

Answer (score 1):

There are two options to achieve this .

**One** is as Jason's said , UploadClass raise an event every time it completes an upload . This is like a **CallBack** method can be used in `Mainfile.xaml.cs` .(Recommanded way)

For example , declare a `UpdateLabelText` Method in `Mainfile.xaml.cs` :

```
public void UpdateLabelText(int index)
{
    //throw new NotImplementedException();
    label.Text = index + " of 5 Images uploaded" ;
}
```

And raise method in **UploadClass** :

```
privat UploadComplete()
{
    ...
    // each image uploaded successfully send it's index
    // such as index == 1/2/3/4/5
    
   Mainfile mainfile = new Mainfile();
   mainfile.UpdateLabelText(1);
}
```

**The another one** is using **[MessageCenter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/messaging-center)** to notify the `Mainfile.xaml.cs` to update `Label` .(Easy way)

For example , Subscribe **MessageCenter** in Mainfile.xaml.cs :

```
public Mainfile()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    
    MessagingCenter.Subscribe<object,int>(this, "Hi", (sender,arg) =>
    {
      // Do something whenever the "Hi" message is received
      label.Text = arg + " of 5 Images uploaded" ;
    });
}
```

and Send Message from `UploadToCloud` complete method of **UploadClass** :

```
privat UploadComplete()
{
    ...
    // each image uploaded successfully send it's index
    // such as index == 1/2/3/4/5
    
    MessagingCenter.Send<object, int>(this, "Hi", index);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I tried both the ways and found out updated values are being passed to the label.Text. But label text is not updating until entire function completes its execution. I just see "5 of 5 images uploaded". I want label to update for each loop cycle. example: "1 of 5 images uploaded" then  "2 of 5 images uploaded" and so one.

Comment: @MYTH That needs `UploadClass` each raise event after each image uploaded . You need to check that whether `UploadClass` has this function .

Comment: @MYTH In general , you need to create a thread queue to upload images . That thread queue contains five thread tasks , each of them finishes the upload task , will notifiy to other class . And better they are sync , until the front task finished , the next will continue . Can refer to this : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.continuewith?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: I'll have a look at this link. I was using the MessagingCenter approach. But i think that does not work within for loop.

Comment: @MYTH Also can share the code of where raising the message , need to check that whehter it calls five times .

Comment: currently am using 2nd approach suggested by you. I simply using for loop inside my UploadImageFunction() 
                foreach (int total in ImagesCount)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Task.Delay(2000).Wait();
                        MessagingCenter.Send<object, int>(this, "Hi", index);
                        index++;
                    }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217073/discussion-between-myth-and-junior-jiang-msft).

Comment: @student Hi , If the reply is helpful, please do not forget to accept it as answer( click the ✔ in the upper left corner of this answer), it will help others who have similar issue. :-)